# Unable to obtain user information when using Google OAUTH2.0 with a Hyperledger Composer REST server

Tags: oauth-2.0, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, google-oauth

I have built a REST server according to the instructions
 [Using Google OAUTH2.0 with a REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) and I was successful. Then I built an application for the client using angular. I obtained the token after the user logged in and successfully interacted with the REST server api.

The problem is that when I use this token to get user information like name, email, ... from google api, it always returns an "Invalid Credentials" error. The API that I use to get information is `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`.
Ex: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=u2dDxaEeECKPAv6HlhQ1eMULWNADvVDHbGTlUjnS7jfUII0fwiHvkzYGD0FmZjuf`

What is my problem? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo` requires authorization.

This means that you need to include the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer <AccessToken>` to call this endpoint.

Here is an example in Go:

```
func displayUserInfo(accessToken string) {
        endpoint := "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"

        req := HttpRequest.NewRequest()

        req.SetHeaders(map[string]string{"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken})

        res, err := req.Get(endpoint)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
                return
        }

        body, err := res.Body()

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
                return
        }

        fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```